# Refresh listview from adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have 2 lists with `CheckBox`. When the user check the `CheckBox` in `list_1` the list item will transferred to `list_2`. It works fine except, I can't refresh the lists from adapter. Tried with `notifyDataSetChanged()` but nothing happens.

In my `MainActivity`:

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, db.getAllTasks(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, false), MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME,false);
mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);    // Set the adapter for list_1

CustomListAdapter adapterDone = new CustomListAdapter(this, db.getAllTasks(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, true),  MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME,true);
listViewDone.setAdapter(adapterDone);    // Set the adapter for list_2
```

And the `getAllTasks` function:

```
public List<Task> getAllTasks(String tableName, boolean done) {
    List<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();

    String op = done ? "1" : "0";
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE done=" + op;
    Log.d(TAG, "query: " + query);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Task task = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            task = new Task();
            task.setTaskText(cursor.getString(0));
            task.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setTime(cursor.getString(2));
            task.setDone(cursor.getInt(3) == 1);
            tasks.add(task);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return tasks;
}
```

Here goes my `Adapter`:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    private static final String TAG = "DTAG";
    private final Activity context;
    private final List<Task> myTasks;
    private final MySQLiteHelper db;
    private final String tableName;
    private final boolean done;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<Task> myTasks, String tableName, boolean done) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_row, myTasks);

        this.context = context;
        this.myTasks = myTasks;
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.done = done;
        db = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);

        final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listMainTextView);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listSubTextView);

        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        ch.setChecked(done);

        ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "position: " + position + " Name: " + myTasks.get(position).getTaskText() + " Checked");
                    db.updateTask(myTasks.get(position).getTaskText(), tableName, true);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "position: " + position + " Name: " + myTasks.get(position).getTaskText() + " UnChecked");
                    db.updateTask(myTasks.get(position).getTaskText(), tableName, false);
                }

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        txtTitle.setText(myTasks.get(position).getTaskText());
        txtSubTitle.setText(myTasks.get(position).getTime() + " " + myTasks.get(position).getDate());

        return rowView;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two separate list of `Task` in your `MainActivity` like this.

```
List<Task> tasksPendingList = new LinkedList<Task>();
List<Task> tasksDoneList = new LinkedList<Task>();
```

Now get the tasks by calling the `getAllTasks` method before initializing the `Adapter`.

```
tasksPendingList = db.getAllTasks(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, false);
tasksDoneList = db.getAllTasks(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, true);
```

Now initialize the adapter like this

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, tasksPendingList, MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, false);
mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);    // Set the adapter for list_1

CustomListAdapter adapterDone = new CustomListAdapter(this, tasksDoneList,  MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, true);
listViewDone.setAdapter(adapterDone);    // Set the adapter for list_2
```

Now inside the `getView` method in your `Adapter` you need to repopulate the lists again to get `notifyDatasetChanged` to work.

```
 ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            db.updateTask(myTasks.get(position).getTaskText(), tableName, true);
        } else {
            db.updateTask(myTasks.get(position).getTaskText(), tableName, false);
        }

        // Just call refreshBothList here
        refreshBothList();
    }
});
```

You might consider taking the refresh mechanism of list outside of your `getView` method in the `MainActivity`.

```
public void refreshBothList() {
    // Repopulate the lists. 
    tasksPendingList = db.getAllTasks(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, false);
    tasksDoneList = db.getAllTasks(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_HOME, true);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapterDone.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You might consider putting the `CustomListAdapter` as a inner class in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: How my CustomListAdapter class can see "tasksPendingList" and "tasksDoneList"?

Comment: Declare them as a public variable.

Comment: Thanks, did this... and your solution seems logical and should work, but still no refresh

Answer (score 1):

you must call get task again after update your database to get new list of tasks and then call notifydatasetchange.
I persoally use cursoradapter in this cases and after change, requery my cursor and call changecursor.
Hope this help you.